# converting Akka's Future[A] to Future[Either[Exception,A]]

Tags: scala, akka, future, scala-2.10, scala-2.9

Is there a method in Akka (or in the standard library in Scala 2.10) to convert a `Future[A]` which might fail into a `Future[Either[Exception,A]]`? I know that you can write

```
f.map(Right(_)).recover {
  case e:Exception => Left(e)
}
```

It just seems to be such a common task that I wonder whether I have overlooked something. I'm interested in answers for Scala 2.9/Akka and Scala 2.10.

Comment: Sympathetic back story at https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-sips/OVz9WSJF1HY/discussion and https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-sips/VRlDgX4yFKE/discussion anyway.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of that signature. Now your Future can have a Throwable in both the Success(Left()) case and the Failure() case.

Comment: @ViktorKlang: You could make the same argument against Option. Now your value has two ways of not existing: `None` and `Some(null)`. But in practice it is understood that we don't ever create a `Some(null)` just like we wouldn't create a `Future[Either...]` which could realistically fail (other than due to OOME or that kind of thing).

Comment: @KimStebel Future[Either[Throwable,T]] is about as useful as Some(null)? Sounds about right

Comment: @ViktorKlang: Haha, very funny. This isn't Twitter though.

Answer (score 13):

The primary reason why this method is missing is that it does not really have good semantics: the static type `Future[Either[Throwable, T]]` does not ensure that that future cannot fail, hence the type change does not gain you much in general.

It can of course make sense if you control all the code which handles those futures, and in that case it is trivial to add it yourself (the name is due to me posting before first coffee, feel free to replace with something better):

```
implicit class FutureOps[T](val f: Future[T]) extends AnyVal {
  def lift(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Either[Throwable,T]] = {
    val p = promise[Either[Throwable,T]]()
    f.onComplete {
      case Success(s)  => p success Right(s)
      case Failure(ex) => p success Left(ex)
    }
    p.future
  }
}
```

It works very similarly with Akka 2.0 futures, hence I leave that exercise to the reader.

Comment: What is wrong with my implementation, except that it doesn't put the method into an implicit class?

Comment: Your implementation creates two additional futures while mine creates only one, so it is just an optimization.

Comment: This is the alternative I meant in my comment to the other answer, but as a nod to Roland's lift, I wrote mine after midnight and called it `packaged` because people talk about packaging the exception; and I had just reviewed the old thread about the axed either method and was sensitive to any name with either in it.  This is an apparently simple exercise in API design that is not so simple; I hope it shows up in a summary blog post for that reason.

Answer (score 4):

Another version of such conversion (in standard Scala):

```
f.transform(tryResult => Success(tryResult.toEither))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would want to do this anyway. Akka 2.0.5's docs show this for `akka.dispatch.Future`:

```
abstract def onComplete[U](func: (Either[Throwable, T]) ⇒ U): Future.this.type
```

So the information that the Future might fail is already embedded into the behavior of a `Future[T]`. The same applies with Scala 2.10's futures, where a future can complete as a `Try[T]` which is similar in purpose to an `Either[Exception, T]`.

```
//in scala.concurrent.Future:
abstract def onComplete[U]
  (func: (Try[T]) ⇒ U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit
```

Comment: onComplete won't work for me, because my method needs to return a future.

Comment: In the sense in which everything is onComplete, an alternative to map and recover is to cut/paste transform to an extension method but amending the failure to success.

Comment: You can still return a Future. My point is that you don't need to do the transformation from `Future[A]` to `Future[Either[Exception, A]]` as it is redundant.