# Future[A] vs Future[Throwable \/ A]

Tags: scala, error-handling, future

Why do some people bother to represent failure in a `scala.concurrent.Future` using scala's `Either` or scalaz's `\/` instead of using the failed state of the Future?

How do you handle errors then and how do you chain calls on the happy path?

---

Update with some examples:

[converting Akka's Future[A] to Future[Either[Exception,A]]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14168712/848128)

[Scalaz Task - the missing documentation](http://timperrett.com/2014/07/20/scalaz-task-the-missing-documentation/)
This one answers the why part, and suggests using `scalaz.EitherT` for chaining calls (that's for `\/`, what about `Either` or `Try`?), but I wonder if one should ever use `Future.failed`, on what conditions, etc, and how to check failure.

I'm not sure if this is a widespread practice though, that's why I'm asking. :)

Comment: This might be a slightly better question with some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I treat the failed state of `Future` the same way I treat exceptions: they're for unexpected failures that indicate either programming errors or system failures like `OutOfMemoryError`s. As such they're not expected to be caught or handled except in a very high-level "retry the whole task" way.

Failed futures are not very typesafe (a failure is just `Throwable`), and can conflate these system-level failures with a more semantic failure that can be handled in a predictable way. So if I have a failure "within" my system, e.g. `Unauthorized`, then I'd rather represent that as an `Either`, something like `Future[Unauthorized \/ MessageData]`. Then there are three possible states:

- `Success(\/-(data))` - success
- `Success(-\/(unauthorized))` - "expected" failure. Something that I know how to handle specificly, e.g. by displaying a particular message to the user or returning a particular return code. Should not set off an alert for the programmer.
- `Failure(throwable)` - unexpected, system-level failure. Can only be handled with a generic error page or some such. Should be setting off monitoring and alerting the programmer.

I used to use a monad transformer to make composing the happy path easier (i.e. `EitherT[Future, Unauthorized, MessageData]`), which works very well, though now I'm looking at a more generic approach (my [scalaz-transfigure](https://github.com/m50d/scalaz-transfigure) library).

Answer (score 4):

I personally use Either inside a future when I have "failures that I can expect" and can do something to recover from them. Especially if I need to make information about possible failures explicit to external users of API

```
sealed trait UserServiceError
case object UserDbNotAvailable extends UserServiceError
case object UserNotFoung extends UserServiceError

def getUser(id: Long): Future[UserServiceError \/ User]
```

This code is much more explicit about what failures can happen. In some cases it can be important.

The same can be achieved with Future[User] and Future.recover but in this case information about possible failures is not in type (can be in documentation)

However I agree that it's very controversial design decision, because Try is already designed for failure handling.

Comment: But when you try to do something with the result you need to check anyway if you received a `User` or a `UserServiceError` so is it really different from pattern matching on `Success(user)` and `Failure(userServiceError)`?

Comment: The advantage I see in `Future[Either[UserServiceError, User]]` is that you can expect what errors you might get, which is nice if you are using an API you didn't write, but are there any other advantages?