# Scala how to call a future function on hashmap items

Tags: scala, scala-collections, scala-cats

I have a hashmap `map: Map[A, Seq[B]]` and I want to call a future function (that returns `Future[Either[Error, Unit]]`) for each `B` in my map.

For example, given the following function `def fooFunc(hashMap: Map[A, Seq[B]]): Future[Either[Error, Unit]]`

I tried something like

```
def fooFunc(hashMap: Map[A, Seq[B]]): Future[Either[Error, Unit]] = {
  val result = for {
   _ <- hashMap.map(entry => 
          entry._2.map( value => 
            Future.sequence(futureFunc(value, entry._1)).liftF
          )
        )
   } yield ()
  result.value
}
```

which gives the compile error `Type mismatch, expected: NotInferedM[Future[NotInferedA]], actual: [Future[Either[Error, Unit]]]`

This is my first time dealing with futures and iterating over hashmap, so I'm confused how to exactly go about this and deal with the Iterable. Any tips would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can map over a `HashMap` just like any other collection such as `List`

```
m.flatMap({ case (key, values) => values.map(f(_, key)) })
```

where `m: Map[A, Seq[B]]` and `f: (B, A) => Future[Unit]`. This returns `Iterable[Future[Unit]]` so we can use `Future.sequence` to invert to `Future[Iterable[Unit]]`

```
m
  .flatMap({ case (key, values) => values.map(f(_, key)) })
  .pipe(Future.sequence(_))
```

Futures internally represent success/failure using `Try` which we can [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52536518/5205022) to `Either` using `transform` and `toEither` like so

```
m                                                           // : Map[A, Seq[B]]
  .flatMap({ case (key, values) => values.map(f(_, key)) }) // : Iterable[Future[Unit]]
  .pipe(Future.sequence(_))                                 // : Future[Iterable[Unit]]
  .map(_ => ())                                             // : Future[Unit]
  .transform(tryResult => Success(tryResult.toEither))      // : Future[Either[Throwable, Unit]]
```

which returns the required `Future[Either[Error, Unit]]` type. The `pipe` method comes from `import util.chaining._`

*<sup>Personally, the transformation from `Map[A, Seq[B]]` to `Future[Either[Error, Unit]]`, feels a bit suspect.</sup>*